# Adding supported languages to a datasource

Tags: localization, internationalization, aem

Certain components in my project have select fields powered by `cq/gui/components/common/datasources/languages` in their Touch UI dialogs.

The customer noticed that some of the locales they need are not present on the OOTB list.

It appears the data source loads a list of available languages from `/libs/wcm/core/resources/languages`. I could overlay these resources by creating a node at `/apps/wcm/core/resources/languages` but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Most documentation that came up in my Google searches pertains to translation workflows and Multi Site Management.

Is overlaying these nodes an acceptable approach or is there a user interface or an API I should use instead?

The nodes at `libs` are accompanied by a `rep:policy` node granting read access to the list of locales to a `language-manager-service` and a `translation-config-service`. There's no hint of anything I could use to actually change the list of available languages though.

Comment: Using the AEM OOTB language datasource might not be the best idea, either. You cant guarantee that adobe wont move it somewhere else or remove it completely in future releases. I suggest that you build your country datasource by yourself, be it manually node-by-node or a script that creates them from an online API or an available “countries” file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an overlay. It did solve the problem with the data source (all languages were present).

Interestingly, the overlay was not taken into account during Tag localisation when using `/libs/cq/tagging/gui/content/tags.html/etc/tags`

We had a Day Care ticket raised and the fix is available in 6.2SP1-CFP14 and, to my understanding, in AEM 6.3 and above.